# wp_localize_script being cached

Tags: cache, nonce

I've faced a problem of nonce value is being cached.
I've embed the nonce in html by using wp_localize_script()

However, the cache plugin has cached this value. Which result in nonce invalid from time to time.

Is there anyway to fix this. I've seen someone tried to fetch nonce value via ajax, but i thought that somehow, there might be a better solution to do this.